# Systemd is eternally stuck on a start-job when I go to boot from my cloned-to NVME. How do I get my system to boot?

Tags: systemd, startup, swap, uuid, nvme

I cloned my hard drive using Clonezilla Live to an NVME SSD. My system is EndeavourOS, Systemd, KDE.

When booting, Systemd makes it to the Basic Machine job and then it starts the `A start job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/034ac866-0a94-4958-a656-d28eb46f5535`. It has no time limit. It will go on for hours if I let it. I've seen that others have it set to go to 90 seconds maximum and then skip. I don't know if that's what I should do (nor how to), but I want whatever is the safest option for my system. Multiple forums have had users with similar issues and they fixed it with a GParted-made Swap partition and adding that partition's UUID to /etc/fstab like `UUID=10a84a8e-3274-43ee-8524-86e2a790d565 none           swap    sw               0 0`. This made no difference, and I would assume it would never make a difference since the start job I'm having the issue with has the UUID for the endeavouros ext4 partition itself (though not the PARTUUID, which I still can't fathom why it is a separate thing).

`sudo blkid` finds the exact same UUID on both the original hard drive and NVME, so if I am needing to replace it in `/etc/fstab` with one that's more specific to the NVME, I don't know how to find it. And I don't know if that even matters either since I even tried the PARTUUID instead, replacing the other UUID in `/etc/fstab` but the start job still lists the exact same way. And yes, I found a forum post where someone had a similar issue with `/etc/fstab` changes not actually changing anything, and a guy suggested looking for .mount files for custom mounts in `/etc/systemd` and `/lib/systemd` but no such luck for *my* situation.

I have absolutely zero clue what I am supposed to do. Please, for the love of God, help me.

Answer (score 3):

[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s are meant to be unique - it's in the name "Universally Unique Identifier".  They're intended to be absolutely unique (i.e. no other device in the world/universe is supposed to have the same UUID), but it's mostly "good enough" if they're unique for a given system (or set of systems where devices with UUIDs may be swapped around).

Anyway, you should **NOT** have two block devices (or filesystems) with the same UUID (the only way you can get that is if you cloned a block device and forgot to change the UUID of either the clone or the original, or if you manually changed the UUID to the same as an existing one).

You need to change the UUID on one of the block devices (preferably the one you **don't** want to be automatically mounted/used by systemd due to the fstab entry - I'd guess this is the one NOT on the NVME drive). How to do this depends on what's on the block device (ext2/3/4 filesystem, swap device, xfs filesystem, etc).

- For a swap device, just run `mkswap` on it again (assuming you're not trying to restart a hibernated system, which doesn't seem to be the case here - `mkswap` would erase any hibernation data)
- For ext2/3/4, you can use `tune2fs`'s `-U` option.
- For xfs, use `xfs_admin`'s `-U` option.

Other filesystem types will have different methods (if they allow the UUID to be changed - not all do).

You can generate a new UUID if needed with the `uuid` command. `mkswap` will generate a new uuid by default, `xfs_admin` will too if you use `generate` as the argument for `-U`, and `tune2fs` will if you use `random` or `time` as the arg for its `-U` option.

I recommend reading the man pages for `mkswap`, `tune2fs`, `xfs_admin`, and `uuid` before changing anything.